# Calling stored procedure, returning value, classic ASP what am I missing?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspUserIsInGroup]
@username varchar(30),
@groupname varchar(30),
@ReturnCount int OUTPUT
    AS
    BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

      SELECT @ReturnCount = count(*)
      FROM sys.database_role_members AS m
      INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dp
         ON m.member_principal_id = dp.principal_id
      INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS l
         ON dp.[sid] = l.[sid]
      INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS r
         ON m.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
      WHERE 1=1
      AND l.name = @username
      AND r.name = @groupname
  END
```

My asp code:

```
 Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 cn.Open db
 Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
 cmd.CommandText = "uspUserIsInGroup"
 cmd.CommandType = 4 '4=adCmdStoredProc

 cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@username", 203, 1, 100, "peds\pss_admin")
 cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@groupname", 203, 1, 100, "rolePSS_admin")
 cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ReturnCount", 200, 2, 255)
 cmd.Execute
 response.write "value returned is: " & cmd.Parameters(2).Value & "<br />"
```

I've tried:

```
 response.write "value returned is: " & cmd.Parameters(2).Value & "<br />"
 response.write "value returned is: " & cmd.Parameters(2) & "<br />"
 response.write "value returned is: " & cmd.Parameters("@ReturnCount").Value & "<br />"
 response.write "value returned is: " & cmd.Parameters("@ReturnCount") & "<br />"
```

I've tried with '@' and without. I've checked the permissions. In call cases I get '0', but the value should be 1.

Running a trace on SQL, this is what's being run:

```
declare @p3 int
set @p3=0
exec uspUserIsInGroup N'peds\pss_admin',N'rolePSS_admin',@p3 output
select @p3
```

Which does give a result of 1.

[image]

What am I doing wrong, what am I missing?  Does it have any thing to do with the fact that when I run the code from the Trace, the result has "(No column name)"?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the asp user running under a different login? They might not have permissions to see all the metadata that your SSMS account does.

Comment: cmd.Parameters(2).Value should be correct. Can you try to modify your SP to return 1 all the time for a test and then examine output? "SELECT @ReturnCount=1;"

Comment: @MartinSmith that was it.  I didn't think it was possible, since I wasn't getting any errors.  But yes, basically when I run the stored procedure logged in under different accounts, I get different results from stored procedure.  If you can make your comment an answer, I'll mark it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments the result of your query can change according to the permissions of the logged in user.

You can use [procedure signing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669102%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you don't want to grant the asp account the required permissions directly.

[`sys.database_principals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx) states

> Any user can see their own user name, the system users, and the fixed
>   database roles. To see other users, requires ALTER ANY USER, or a
>   permission on the user. To see user-defined roles, requires ALTER ANY
>   ROLE, or membership in the role.

[`sys.database_role_members`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189780.aspx) states

> Any user can view their own role membership. To view other role
>   memberships requires membership in the db_securityadmin fixed database
>   role or VIEW DEFINITION on the database.

[`sys.server_principals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx) states

> Any login can see their own login name, the system logins, and the
>   fixed server roles. To see other logins, requires ALTER ANY LOGIN, or
>   a permission on the login. To see user-defined server roles, requires
>   ALTER ANY SERVER ROLE, or membership in the role.

Answer (score 0):

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@username", 203, 1, 100, "peds\pss_admin")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@groupname", 203, 1, 100, "rolePSS_admin")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ReturnCount", 200, 2, 255)

-should be-

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@username", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30, "peds\pss_admin")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@groupname", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30, "rolePSS_admin")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ReturnCount",adInteger,adParamOutput)
```

where adInteger = 3, adParamOutput = 2, adVarChar = 200

so your statement output parameter using hard-coded numbers should read:

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ReturnCount", 3, 2)
```